# Why did Lex Luthor tell Mercy to call his attorney?

Tags: dc, superman, lex-luthor, superman-brainiac-attacks

At the end of *Superman: Brainiac Attacks*, a Kryptonite orb in Brainiac's body was found to have the Lex Corp label. Luthor then told Mercy to call his attorney in front of everyone. It was like he was all out of options...

Initially, in the telefilm, Brainiac attacked Lex Labs. Why couldn't Lex Luthor say that Brainiac might have stolen that piece from his Lab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lex is confronted with the orb in hospital. Several police have just arrived and he's the victim of a serious (albeit true) allegation that he was in league with Brainiac.

[image: Lexcorp Kryptonite orb]

Regardless of whether he can simply talk his way out of the accusation later, the simple fact is that the allegation has been made. Someone as smart as Luthor knows that you should [never talk the police](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Au4_EdPwTkE) without a lawyer present.

Also, the remark about calling his lawyers ("*all of them*") is made as a 'stage whisper' to his bodyguard rather than something that everyone is expected to hear.

[image: Lex Luthor]